# How to retain original file ownership information While recovering files from windows server sbs2011 backup

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup-restoration, windows-sbs-2011, permissions, documents

### **Background:**

- Windows SBS2011/2008 R2 Microsoft
- Word Documents
- Windows built in backup and restore

### **Plot:**

Some user/s moved some sensitive files to a public network drive and I was told to move them immediately and find out who did it. Without thinking much I move them and while doing so over wrote the owner info in [File-->rightclick-->properties-->Details Tab--> under File "Owner"]

### **Things Tried:**

I tried restoring them from backup but that information seems to get overwritten with my login user/current user on the server.

### Any Idea How I can get that info????

Comment: Moving files shouldn't change the "Owner". That's odd.

Comment: Verified on sbs2011 and wind 2008 r2 enterprise..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the following may sound silly, but keep in mind SBS was designed for organizations without an IT department.  You want to have the user restore their own files via Windows Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for your input but restoring is no the issue. After restoring the original file attributes for "Ownership" gets reset any other way to restore this file to keep the original file attributes, ownership, permission intact from windows backup?

Comment: @zman If they restore the files from a shadow copy, the ownership will be intact.

Comment: Thanks again.. but no luck there wasn't any previous versions on those files in that location

Comment: You solved it !!!!Thanks I was able to get it back I tried shadow copy few days earlier with the entire folder